# Thank you very much for your help. / Thank you very much for the help

Tags: phrase-choice

> **Thank you** very much **for your help**.
>
> **Thank you** very much **for (the) help**.

I know the first sentence is common, but I'm trying to understand why the second one isn't. Because of "help" is a noun and there is a need to use an article if we don't use a pronoun. So, the second sentence doesn't sound so good as the first sentence. That's why the first sentence is more common in usage. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any grammar reason for the first sentence being more common, simply we are making the thanks more personal.  We thank for the help *that you have offered* (ie "your help") not just "the help".